# Family reunion visa - Germany

Tags: germany

Can we apply directly for family reunion permit at immigration office if we are holding a residence of a schengen state?

Both husband and wife are holding non-EU passports. (Furthermore, the spouse in Germany had put forward permanent residence application)

Comment: A bit more details please. Is the EU Citizen moving to Germany? Is is present permit an Article 10/20 permit? If both answers are yes, then the answer is yes.

Comment: I have updated the question with specific details. @MarkJohnson

Comment: Yes, see details on this site for Berlin: [Residence permit for spouses, parents and children of foreign citizens (general) - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/305289/en/)